# Count How Many Letters In A List With 'n' Input

Tags: python, list, count

Basically i wanted to know how to count the number of letters in a list, for example lets say i add the word 'EXAMPLE' to a list and then lets say i wanna find out how many times the letter 'e' is used given e as the user input how would i write it so it says there are 2 e's in the word 'EXAMPLE'.

So far i got

```
WordList = []
print("1. Enter A Word")
print("2. Check Letter Or Vowel Times")


userInput = input("Please Choose An Option: ")
if userInput == "1":
    wordInput = input("Please Enter A Word: ")
    WordList.append(wordInput.lower())
```

Comment: If you want to count the letters in a single word, you need some way of selecting the right word from `WordList`.

Answer (score 1):

I isolated your problem. Use collections' Counter for this:

```
from collections import Counter

wordInput = input("Please Enter A Word: ").lower()
wordDict = Counter(wordInput) # converts to dictionary with counts

letterInput = input("Please Enter A Letter: ").lower() 

print(wordDict.get(letterInput,0)) # return counts of letter (0 if not found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['example']

def count(y):
    for x in l:
        return x.count(y)

count('e')
```

Without using built-in function `count()`

```
l=list('example')

def count(y):
    cnt=0
    for x in l:
        if x == y:
            cnt+=1
    return cnt

print(count('e'))
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without built in functions like count?

Comment: any clues on how? i'm trying to tweak ur old version around but not getting any results :/